# How to make a search keyword through javascript and only display the snippet of the keyword?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Today I have a requirement, I hope that the block containing the keyword can be displayed when searching for the keyword in the input box! Instead of just turning keywords into red. Current progress: But currently I can only turn keywords into red. Difficulty encountered: How to make the snippets without keywords disappear, and only the content containing keywords appears. I have encountered difficulties here and tried for more than 3 hours, but I still don’t know how to achieve it. Hope to get your help, thank you. The image below is what I would expect to see after searching for keywords.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#js-search").on('click', function() {
    let keyword = $("#keyWord").val()
    $("p").each(function(index, el) {
      if (el.innerText.includes(keyword)) {
        el.innerText = el.innerText.replace(keyword, `<span class="red">${keyword}</span>`)
      }
      $(this).html(el.innerText);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="keyWord" type="text"><button id="js-search">search</button>

<ul>
  <li>
    <h1>about giving back</h1>
    <p>This is the content of the answer about giving back</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>Credit Card Payment Issues</h1>
    <p>Credit card payment question content</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>return the goods</h1>
    <p>Content related to return issues</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>register</h1>
    <p>How to register as a member</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40tBy.png)

Comment: so you want only the elements containing the searched text and hide elements without the keyword? do you care about `h1` containing keyword?

Comment: @deppermYes, I just want to display the part that contains keywords. The display here includes the entire li block, so h1 also needs to be displayed.

Comment: @user229044
If he only turns white, but his position still occupies that space, this should not be the result I want, thank you for the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem,its hide the parent element if its not contains the word that you searching for, otherwise it will be shown

```js
$(function() {
  $("#js-search").on('click', function() {
    let keyword = $("#keyWord").val()
    $("p").each(function(index, el) {
      if (el.innerText.includes(keyword)) {
        // Without the following line the elements that you already get them as a result previously, will still hidden so you need to show them again
        $(el).parent().show();
        el.innerText = el.innerText.replace(keyword, `<span class="red">${keyword}</span>`)
      } else {
        $(el).parent().hide();
      }
      $(this).html(el.innerText);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="keyWord" type="text"><button id="js-search">search</button>

<ul>
  <li>
    <h1>about giving back</h1>
    <p>This is the content of the answer about giving back</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>Credit Card Payment Issues</h1>
    <p>Credit card payment question content</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>return the goods</h1>
    <p>Content related to return issues</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>register</h1>
    <p>How to register as a member</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple. You just need to hide the parents of the elements NOT matching your keyword.

Like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#js-search").on('click', function() {
    let keyword = $("#keyWord").val()
    $("p").each(function(index, el) {
      if (el.innerText.includes(keyword)) {
        el.innerText = el.innerText.replace(keyword, `<span class="red">${keyword}</span>`)
      }
      else{
        $(el).closest("li").hide();
      }
      $(this).html(el.innerText);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="keyWord" type="text"><button id="js-search">search</button>

<ul>
  <li>
    <h1>about giving back</h1>
    <p>This is the content of the answer about giving back</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>Credit Card Payment Issues</h1>
    <p>Credit card payment question content</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>return the goods</h1>
    <p>Content related to return issues</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>register</h1>
    <p>How to register as a member</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to hide and show parents :

```js
$(function() {
  $("#js-search").on('click', function() {
    let keyword = $("#keyWord").val()
    $("p").each(function(index, el) {
      if (el.innerText.includes(keyword)) {
        el.innerText = el.innerText.replace(keyword, `<span class="red">${keyword}</span>`)
        $(el).parent().show()
      }else $(el).parent().hide()
      $(this).html(el.innerText);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="keyWord" type="text"><button id="js-search">search</button>

<ul>
  <li>
    <h1>about giving back</h1>
    <p>This is the content of the answer about giving back</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>Credit Card Payment Issues</h1>
    <p>Credit card payment question content</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>return the goods</h1>
    <p>Content related to return issues</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>register</h1>
    <p>How to register as a member</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```